# How to set color for the first character injected with function to label/placeholder?

Tags: css

I want to make this "*" red as required caution but useing ::first-letter I'm grab also first letter
is there something like ::first-charcter? or any other solution?

```
 <v-autocomplete
   class="custom-label-color"
   item-value="id"
   item-text="name"
   :rules="nameRules"
   required
   v-bind:label="dictionaryName(ac...)"
   v-model="ac..."
   :items="dictionaryPositions(ac...)"
   ></v-autocomplete>
```

```
 dictionaryName(id) {
   let a = this.dictionaries.filter(i => i.id == id)
   try {
   return "*"+ a[0].name
   } catch {
   return ''
}
```

```
.custom-label-color label::first-letter{
  color: red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `::first-letter` is supposed to work like this, and nothing like `::first-character` or similar exists. You will either need to wrap this `*` into an HTML element, so that you can format that element differently, or use some other mechanism like a pseudo element to insert it (based on setting an additional class for those elements or something.)

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) with regard to what is selected by `::first-letter`: "Punctuation that precedes or immediately follows the first letter is included in the match."